# Llamar un procedimiento almacenado con las instrucciones de Command en Entity Framework en C#

Tags: c#

estoy queriendo llamar un procedimiento almacenado, utilizando las funciones o los comandos *Command*, *Entity Framework*, en *C#* con *Winform*. Este es mi codigo:

```
public static string mpxGeneraCodigoCliente(string pcMaximoCodigo, int pnIdEmpresa)
        {
            // Declaracion de Variables que retornaran el resultado del sp
            string acReturnProximoCodigo = string.Empty;
            string acReturnPrefijo = string.Empty;
            string acReturnMaximo = string.Empty;
            // Capturar la Excepción del mensaje del error.
            try
            {
                // Realizar la cadena de conexion'C00181'           "DXAClientes.Properties.Settings.mCnxSIAFCORE"
                //using (EntityConnection entityConnection = new EntityConnection("name=SIAFCOREEntities"))
                using (EntityConnection entityConnection = new EntityConnection("name=DXAClientes.Properties.Settings.mCnxSIAFCORE"))
                {
                    // Habrir la conexion con el servidor servidor
                    entityConnection.Open();

                    EntityCommand cmdEntityCommand = entityConnection.CreateCommand();
                    cmdEntityCommand.CommandText = "CNF.mpxMaxCodEntGet";
                    cmdEntityCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmdEntityCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;

                    // Configurar los parametros del SP Command
                    EntityParameter pnIDECIA = new EntityParameter();
                    EntityParameter pcMascara = new EntityParameter();
                    EntityParameter pnLongitud = new EntityParameter();
                    EntityParameter pnvalor_consecutivo = new EntityParameter();
                    EntityParameter pcEsquema_Tabla = new EntityParameter();

                    // Asignando los valores a los parametros
                    pnIDECIA.Value = pnIdEmpresa;
                    pcMascara.Value = "C99999";
                    pnLongitud.Value = 6;
                    pnvalor_consecutivo.Value = pcMaximoCodigo;
                    pcEsquema_Tabla.Value = "CLI.MSTCLI";

                    // Asignando los nombres a los parametros
                    pnIDECIA.ParameterName = "@pnIDECIA";
                    pcMascara.ParameterName = "@pcMascara";
                    pnLongitud.ParameterName = "@pnLongitud";
                    pnvalor_consecutivo.ParameterName = "@pnvalor_consecutivo";
                    pcEsquema_Tabla.ParameterName = "@CLI.MSTCLI";

                    // Agregar los parametros a la fuente de datos
                    cmdEntityCommand.Parameters.Add(pnIDECIA);
                    cmdEntityCommand.Parameters.Add(pcMascara);
                    cmdEntityCommand.Parameters.Add(pnLongitud);
                    cmdEntityCommand.Parameters.Add(pnvalor_consecutivo);
                    cmdEntityCommand.Parameters.Add(pcEsquema_Tabla);

                    // Execute the Command. // Executar el command del Activo fija.
                    using (EntityDataReader aoEDR = cmdEntityCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
                    {
                        // Read the results returned  by the store procedure
                        // Leer el resultado del SP y retonar el valor
                        while (aoEDR.Read())
                        {
                            acReturnPrefijo = aoEDR["Prefijo"].ToString();
                            acReturnMaximo = aoEDR["Maximo"].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                XtraMessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error - Codigo de Cliente", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            // armo el codigo generado o devuelto por el SP para retonarlo al control
            acReturnProximoCodigo = acReturnPrefijo.Trim() + acReturnMaximo.Trim();
            // Retorna el nuevo codigo del empleado
            return acReturnProximoCodigo.ToString().Trim();
        }
```

El error que me manda es al momento de querer abrir la conexión. Según el ejemplo que encontré. Me manda el siguiente mensaje de error.

> La conexión con nombre especificado no se encuentra en la
>   configuración, no es apropiada para ser utilizada con el proveedor de
>   *EntityClient*, o no es válida.

He cambiado el `name` y probado varias opciones o ejemplos. Espero una luz de su parte.

Saludos.

Comment: tienes que hacerlo así? lo digo porque es momento de cambiar, no está soportado ya por Microsoft.(https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entityclient.entityconnection.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_EntityClient_EntityConnection__ctor_System_String_) y luego voy a https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: que version de EF estas utilizando ? se trata de EF6

Comment: Si usas EF6, no te conviene mapear el procedure con una entidad para que sea transparente, si te interesa ir por este lado puedo explicarte como hacerlo. No creo que este camino que planteas sea el correcto

Comment: Si leandro estoy con EF6, creo que es la 6.1.2 exactamente, te lo agradeceria mucho si no hay problema, usted me indica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ejecutar un `procedure` dentro del ambiente de `EF` necesitas aplicar

[Execute Raw SQL Queries in Entity Framework 6](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/raw-sql-query-in-entity-framework.aspx)

[Raw SQL Queries](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql)

Tienes que crear una clase que mapea con los datos que recibes

```
public class CodigoCliente 
{
   public string Prefijo {get;set;}
   public string Maximo {get;set;}
}
```

Entonces usas para ejecutar

```
List<CodigoCliente> codigoClientes = null;

using(var ctx = new NombreDbContext()) 
{
    codigoClientes = dbcontext.Database.SqlQuery<CodigoCliente>(
                    "CNF.mpxMaxCodEntGet @pnIDECIA, @pcMascara, @pnLongitud, @pnvalor_consecutivo, @CLI.MSTCLI",
                       new SqlParameter("@pnIDECIA",pnIdEmpresa),
                       new SqlParameter("@pcMascara", "C99999"),
                       new SqlParameter("@pnLongitud", 6),
                       new SqlParameter("@pnvalor_consecutivo", pcMaximoCodigo),
                       new SqlParameter("@CLI.MSTCLI", "CLI.MSTCLI")).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Gracias Leandro, pero no me funciona entre a unas paginas navegando y le agrege eso, no me devulve nada y le agregue mas opciones.

rd

Comment: cuando dice "no me funciona" es porque obtienes algun error o simplemente no obtienes ningun registro, porque hay mucha la diferencia segun el problema. Sino obtuviste datos prueba de definir en el procedure un select pero sin parametros, puede que para los valores que le pasas no haya registros, despues ve agregandolos de a uno para evaluar cual es el que no genera resultados

Comment: desconozo cuales paginas hayas navegado y que le hayas agregado, sino lo mencionas

Comment: Entre a los link que me pasaste, primero le agregue:
using (var ctx = new SIAFCOREEntities())
                {
{ }
para que me presentara var aoResult = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<CodigoCliente>(, 
si no le agrego ese no me sale esta opcion de DataBase, o me da error Sql Query.
y al final un tolist()

Comment: ok eso es correcto, entendi ya venias usando EF por eso no lo aclare, es sabido que hay que instanciar el contexto de EF para poder usarlo. Mas alla de eso que agregaste, lo cual es correcto, porque dices que no funciona? intentaste quitar del procedure los filtros de los parametros para ir agregandolo de a uno y ver cual es el que genera que no tengas resultados? esa es una buena prueba, porque puede que este todo correcto pero sino hay registros para los datos que asignas por parametro no te va a retornar nada

Comment: Listo, hice las correciones, modifque un par de nombre en la llamada y ya lo tengo funcionando, gracias Mrs. Leandro Tuttini, ahora a descansar un rato.